# DisMissState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem when I try to delete the item and it doesn't accept to delete the item. I am using ConfirmDismiss.

[image]

Error:

> **Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'**
> **_DisMissState.build..
> (package:advanced_part_2/dismissible.dart:84:30)**
>
> **_DismissibleState._handleDismissStatusChanged
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/dismissible.dart:498:11)**

Code:

```
 confirmDismiss: (DismissDirection dir) async {
                if (dir == DismissDirection.startToEnd) {
              //    AlertDialog ad =
                  final bool res = await showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        content: Text('Are You Sure you want to delete'),
                        actions:<Widget> [
                          ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                'cancel',

                              )),
                          ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  genList.removeAt(index);
                                });
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                'Delete',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                              ))
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  );
                  return res;
                } else {
                  return true;
                }
              },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because when your calling the following code:

```
final bool res = await showDialog(...);
```

it will return a null value, see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html

And, you also not giving any return value when clicking the button:

```
ElevatedButton(
     onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context).pop();
      },
      child: Text(
        'cancel',

      )),
```

You can't use `Navigator.of(context).pop();`. Instead, you need to use either:

```
Navigator.pop(context, false);
```

or

```
Navigator.pop(context, true);
```

Then, after that, you need to handle the nullable returned value from show dialog by giving a default value when null. Something like this:

```
bool res = await showDialog(...);
if(res == null) res = false;
```

Comment: In the last code block: it should be `bool? res` since it's nullable.

Comment: Can you see the full code at this link? [link](https://pickle-fold-909.notion.site/Null-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-bool-_DisMissState-build-1bc3c894e58f420a85c31e25848b560a)
I have tried to solve the problem but to no avail

Comment: @osaxma: Thank you for reminding me. I forget to add it.

Comment: @Mohammadalqannas: You can slightly change the code to: `bool res = await showDialog(...)??false;` or `bool? res = await showDialog(...);
if(res == null) res = false;
return res!;`

Answer (score 0):

showDialog can return `null` when the dialog is dismissed (e.g. user clicks outside the dialog) so you've to account for that by changing the type to:

```dart
final bool? res = await showDialog(/* your code */);
```

then in your logic below, you have to check for null:

```dart
if(res == null) {
 // handle dismiss
} else if (res == false) {
 // handle cancel
} else {
 // handle confirm/true
}
```

As @Er1 mentioned in the comment, you'll also need to pass `true` or `false` when popping the dialog:

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
// or
Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
```

The above still applies since `barrierDismissible` is `true` by default.

Comment: The dialog will always return null because nothing is passed to `pop()`

Comment: @Er1 .. true, I missed that and I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
final bool res = await showDialog(
                    context: context,
                    barrierDismissible: false,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return AlertDialog(
                        content: Text('Are You Sure you want to delete'),
                        actions:<Widget> [
                          ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                'cancel',

                              )),
                          ElevatedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  genList.removeAt(index);
                                });
                                Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                              },
                              child: Text(
                                'Delete',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                              ))
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  );
```

Add `false` and `true` to the `pop()` to make the `showDialog` return a boolean.

But keep in mind if you don't set `barrierDismissible` in `showDialog` to `false` you can get `null` returned if you tap outside of the dialog.

Comment: it should be `final bool? res =` since `showDialog` can return `null`

Comment: @osaxma not if you set `barrierDismissible` to `false`

Comment: Now you edited it yes, but it's `true` by default and the question has it that way...